# Iterating through a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where one column represents if the location value in another column changed in the row below it. As an example,

```
2013-02-05 19:45:00   (39.94, -86.159)     True
2013-02-05 19:50:00   (39.94, -86.159)     True
2013-02-05 19:55:00   (39.94, -86.159)    False
2013-02-05 20:00:00  (39.777, -85.995)    False
2013-02-05 20:05:00  (39.775, -85.978)     True
2013-02-05 20:10:00  (39.775, -85.978)     True
2013-02-05 20:15:00  (39.775, -85.978)    False
2013-02-05 20:20:00   (39.94, -86.159)     True
2013-02-05 20:30:00   (39.94, -86.159)    False
```

So, what I want to do is go row by row through this dataframe and check for the rows with `False`. And then (may be add another column) which has total 'continuous' time spent in that place. The same place can be visited again like in the example above. In that case it is taken to be as a separate condition. So, for the above example, something like:

```
2013-02-05 19:45:00   (39.94, -86.159)     True    0
2013-02-05 19:50:00   (39.94, -86.159)     True    0
2013-02-05 19:55:00   (39.94, -86.159)    False   15
2013-02-05 20:00:00  (39.777, -85.995)    False    5  
2013-02-05 20:05:00  (39.775, -85.978)     True    0
2013-02-05 20:10:00  (39.775, -85.978)     True    0
2013-02-05 20:15:00  (39.775, -85.978)    False   15
2013-02-05 20:20:00   (39.94, -86.159)     True    0 
2013-02-05 20:25:00   (39.94, -86.159)    False   10
```

I would then plot a histogram of these 'continuous' time spent using the hist() function per day. How would I get the second dataframe from the first by iterating through the dataframe? I'm new to python and pandas and the real datafile is huge so, I would need something reasonably efficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's another take

```
df['group'] = (df.condition == False).astype('int').cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0)

df
             date    long     lat condition  group
2/5/2013 19:45:00  39.940 -86.159      True      0
2/5/2013 19:50:00  39.940 -86.159      True      0
2/5/2013 19:55:00  39.940 -86.159     False      0
2/5/2013 20:00:00  39.777 -85.995     False      1
2/5/2013 20:05:00  39.775 -85.978      True      2
2/5/2013 20:10:00  39.775 -85.978      True      2
2/5/2013 20:15:00  39.775 -85.978     False      2
2/5/2013 20:20:00  39.940 -86.159      True      3
2/5/2013 20:25:00  39.940 -86.159     False      3

df['result'] = df.groupby(['group']).date.transform(lambda sdf: 5 *len(sdf))

df
             date    long     lat condition  group result
2/5/2013 19:45:00  39.940 -86.159      True      0     15
2/5/2013 19:50:00  39.940 -86.159      True      0     15
2/5/2013 19:55:00  39.940 -86.159     False      0     15
2/5/2013 20:00:00  39.777 -85.995     False      1      5
2/5/2013 20:05:00  39.775 -85.978      True      2     15
2/5/2013 20:10:00  39.775 -85.978      True      2     15
2/5/2013 20:15:00  39.775 -85.978     False      2     15
2/5/2013 20:20:00  39.940 -86.159      True      3     10
2/5/2013 20:25:00  39.940 -86.159     False      3     10
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need 0.11-dev. I think this will give you what you are looking for. See this section: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-deltas for more info as the timedeltas are a newer data that pandas is supporting

Heres your data (I separated long/lat just for convenience, the key thing is that
the condition column is a bool)

```
In [137]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(data),index_col=0,parse_dates=True)

In [138]: df
Out[138]: 
               date    long       lat condition
2013-02-05 19:45:00  39.940   -86.159      True
2013-02-05 19:50:00  39.940   -86.159      True
2013-02-05 19:55:00  39.940   -86.159     False
2013-02-05 20:00:00  39.777   -85.995     False
2013-02-05 20:05:00  39.775   -85.978      True
2013-02-05 20:10:00  39.775   -85.978      True
2013-02-05 20:15:00  39.775   -85.978     False
2013-02-05 20:20:00  39.940   -86.159      True
2013-02-05 20:25:00  39.940   -86.159     False

In [139]: df.dtypes
Out[139]: 
date         float64
long lat     float64
condition       bool
dtype: object
```

Create some date columns that are the index (these are datetime64[ns] dtype)

```
In [140]: df['date'] = df.index   
In [141]: df['rdate'] = df.index
```

Set the rdate column that are False to NaT (np.nan's are transformed to NaT)

```
In [142]: df.loc[~df['condition'],'rdate'] = np.nan
```

Forward fill the NaT's from the previous value

```
In [143]: df['rdate'] = df['rdate'].ffill()
```

Subtract the rdate from the date, this produces a timedelta64[ns] type column 
of the time differences

```
In [144]: df['diff'] = df['date']-df['rdate']

In [151]: df
Out[151]: 
                                   date  long lat condition               rdate  \
2013-02-05 19:45:00 2013-02-05 19:45:00   -86.159      True 2013-02-05 19:45:00   
2013-02-05 19:50:00 2013-02-05 19:50:00   -86.159      True 2013-02-05 19:50:00   
2013-02-05 19:55:00 2013-02-05 19:55:00   -86.159     False 2013-02-05 19:50:00   
2013-02-05 20:00:00 2013-02-05 20:00:00   -85.995     False 2013-02-05 19:50:00   
2013-02-05 20:05:00 2013-02-05 20:05:00   -85.978      True 2013-02-05 20:05:00   
2013-02-05 20:10:00 2013-02-05 20:10:00   -85.978      True 2013-02-05 20:10:00   
2013-02-05 20:15:00 2013-02-05 20:15:00   -85.978     False 2013-02-05 20:10:00   
2013-02-05 20:20:00 2013-02-05 20:20:00   -86.159      True 2013-02-05 20:20:00   
2013-02-05 20:25:00 2013-02-05 20:25:00   -86.159     False 2013-02-05 20:20:00   

                        diff  
2013-02-05 19:45:00 00:00:00  
2013-02-05 19:50:00 00:00:00  
2013-02-05 19:55:00 00:05:00  
2013-02-05 20:00:00 00:10:00  
2013-02-05 20:05:00 00:00:00  
2013-02-05 20:10:00 00:00:00  
2013-02-05 20:15:00 00:05:00  
2013-02-05 20:20:00 00:00:00  
2013-02-05 20:25:00 00:05:00
```

The diff column are now timedelta64[ns], so you want integers in minutes
(FYI this is a little bit clunky now as pandas doesn't have a scalar type 
Timedelta similar to Timestamp for dates)

(Also, you may have have to do a shift() on this rdate series before you ffill, I think I am off by 1 somewhere)...but this is the idea

```
In [175]: df['diff'].map(lambda x: x.item().seconds/60)
Out[175]: 
2013-02-05 19:45:00     0
2013-02-05 19:50:00     0
2013-02-05 19:55:00     5
2013-02-05 20:00:00    10
2013-02-05 20:05:00     0
2013-02-05 20:10:00     0
2013-02-05 20:15:00     5
2013-02-05 20:20:00     0
2013-02-05 20:25:00     5
```

Comment: You can also do `ffill(inplace=True)` to avoid creating a temporary array copy.