# Efficient loop through two Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes:

The first frame contains a timestamp (Date + Time) and four sets of lat/long pairs that define the corners of a box on the earth.

The second frame contains a timestamp and one lat/long pair that marks an event.

I want to find out, for each event, whether it fell inside any of the 'boxes on the earth', and if so, which ones and what is the delta_t between the timestamps.

The only way I can think of doing this is to loop through the second frame, row by row, and compare to the first frame.  I'm hoping for a more pythonic way, but nothing is coming to mind.  Any ideas?

Thanks,

SH

Comment: You could create an MxN dataframe and iterate through it. Will be more readable, but it probably won't be more efficient in time or space

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question: [Iterating through a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683588/iterating-through-a-pandas-dataframe)

I think this will work. Pseudo codish. You will need 0.11-dev

Both frames have a a datetime index, A is your first one, B is much shorter as it only has your events.

on A, set the index as a column, `A['date'] = A.index`

on B, set the index as a column, `B['date'] = B.index`

inner join A and B, then ffill on B

```
C = A.join(B).ffill()
```

Then you want some boolean logic if your event is included, something like:

```
C['is_included'] = (C['A_lat'] > C['B_lat']) & (C['A_long'] > C['B_long'])...etc
```

So when the is_included is True, you want the differential time but from the previous event

Set the non-selected events to nan on the original date column of B

```
C['date_B'][~C['is_included']] = np.nan
```

Forward fill the date_B's again

```
C['date_B'] = C['date_B'].ffill()
```

If you now subtract date_B from date_A I think you will have your timedelta

```
C['delta'] = C['date_B']-C['date_A']
```

then

```
C[C['is_included']] is your answer, and delta is the timedelta
```