# pandas time series join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames one with events that may or may not trigger action.  The other represents Actions with a field to show what triggered the action.  My goal is to get as many trigger to action durations as I can.  
The keys are not under my control and not a perfect equal join where one and only one match is found.  My though is to do the join then remove negative durations because I know triggers must precede actions. Then I need to remove all but the lowest duration for each key.  See sample code.  I want all the action fields ‘other_data’ in the result_df.  (Only for the joins of minimum duration) 
I know that my result may include some artificially short durations but I suspect due to the nature of the join key reuse that this will happen seldom and do not pose a problem for the rest of the analysis.  Previously I had been using arbitrarily selected max durations to toss out erroneous join data but tossing these outliers will be problematic because high outliers are what I am most interested in.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

scale = 10000 # can go low like 1000 or high like a million just for dummmy data
trigger_df = pd.DataFrame({'seq_key' : np.random.random_integers(scale * .02,scale *     .2,scale * 7),
                           'time_ns' : np.random.random_integers(scale * .04,scale * .4,scale * 7)})

action_df = pd.DataFrame({'seq_key' : np.random.random_integers(scale * .02,scale * .2,scale * .7),
                       'time_ns' : np.random.random_integers(scale * .04,scale * .4,scale * .7),
                       'other_data' : np.random.random_integers(scale * .03,scale * .3,scale * .7)})
action_df.drop_duplicates(cols='seq_key', take_last=True)

join_df = pd.merge(action_df,trigger_df, 
            on='seq_key', how='inner',
            suffixes=('_action','_trigger'))
join_df['duration_ns'] = join_df.time_ns_action - join_df.time_ns_trigger
join_df = join_df[join_df.duration_ns > 0]

grouped = join_df.groupby(by = ['seq_key'])['duration_ns']
result_df = pd.DataFrame({'duration_ns' : grouped.min()}).reset_index()
print average(result_df.duration_ns)
print average(join_df.duration_ns)
print result_df ,'sad df wants other_data'
```

Comment: this is a somewhat similar question, accomplished in a different manner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683588/iterating-through-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Thanks Looks fancy.
1. Join like normal
2. Add field for my duration_ns
3. order the result DF by the join key and the duration [descending order] (will look into that)
4. create a new Boolean field making use of the shift(1) comparing the current record to see next has a lower duration but the same key.  (also need to play around with this idea)
5. select out all the records where my new bool field indicates that it is the lowest for its key.
Does it sound like I have a handle on the suggestion?  I will update my post if I get it working.

Comment: you also might find some of these recipes useful: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html, e.g. you may actually need to look several periods (and not just 1 on your shift), but you idea looks about right